# explicit configuration of durable topic

Tags: activemq-classic

It seems quite hard to find a way to configure explicitly activeMQ topics
Is there a cofn file and a reference page to make configuration explicitly

The idea is to declare new durable topics and consumers (with static Id)

any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/configure-startup-destinations.html) states, you can configure destinations in the XML configuration (`activemq.xml`), .e.g:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
   <destinations>
      <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR" />
      <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC" />
   </destinations>
</broker>
```